# Groovy "Cannot invoke method dirset() on null object

Tags: groovy

I'm getting the above error when I run the following code at mydirset=getDirset() as a null pointer exception, however it will work if I do a println in main. Any suggestions as to what I've missed?

```
static final String mydirset = getDirset()

static String getDirset( String baseFolder , String relativePathToFile )
{
    println baseFolder
    println relativePathToFile
    def exclude = ant.dirset(id: "dirset" ,dir: "${baseFolder}")
    {
        present(targetdir: baseFolder)
        {
              mapper(type: "glob", from: "*" , to: "*/" + relativePathToFile)
        }
    }

return "" + exclude
}
```

Comment: Is `ant` null? Try replacing `ant.dirset` with `new AntBuilder().dirset`

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by replacing static final String mydirset = getDirset() with static final String mydirset; static{ mydirset = getDirset()} testing now

Comment: I can't see where `mydirset` is used in the code above...

Comment: It isn't, just assigning it caused the exception this is just the snippet causing the problem. Wrapping the assignment in a static {} block fixed the issue, now I just have to figure out why :)

Comment: An obvious problem is that the first line calls the `getDirset` method without passing any arguments.

Comment: Sorry, you can assume it passes the arguments, I generalized the code here to avoid posting huge chunks